# Select box does not have border

Tags: css

The following css file works fine in providing the background colour and border to a textfield but does not provide the border to the select box.

```
.fieldSClsErr {
    font: normal 0.75em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0; 
    color:black;
    line-height:120%;
    width:200px;
    height:18px;
    border:1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-color: red red red red;
    background-color:#fffff0;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin:0px;
}
```

#### Question

How can I modify this css code so that I get a border around a select box?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title - Also, you should also show some HTML to give us enough information to replace the issue.

Comment: Please share your HTML because as it stands, [I see no issues](http://jsfiddle.net/TBBX4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/2Wyyj/

```
<select class="fieldSClsErr" style="width: 80%;">
    <option value="Sal">Sal</option>
    <option value="Awesome">Awesome!</option>
  </select>

  <input class="fieldSClsErr" type="text" />
```

css

```
.fieldSClsErr{
display:inline-block;
    font: normal 0.75em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0; 
    color:black;
    line-height:120%;
    width:200px;
    height:18px;
    border: 2px solid red !important;
    background-color:#fffff0;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of `display: inline-block` here?

Comment: I normally put it in to get rid of default styles like input boxes to give them a perfect rectangle that i can apply my own shadows and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Your [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border) syntax is wrong :

```
- border:1px solid #b3b3b3;
- border-color: red red red red;

+ border: red 1px solid;
```

Comment: OK, I should have said weird. If you are going to set the border of a single DOM element, you might as well set in in a single statement. I'm just saying. Should have been a comment. You are right.

Comment: It is not wrong. It can be set anyway you want. Yes, but there are complexities with IE. Sometimes, IE does'nt take that.